# flutter how to randomize splash screens in android

Tags: android, xml, flutter, dart

I am currently writing a flutter project in dart and build the android app from flutter. I currently have an image that covers the entire screen as the splash screen. Now I want to provide other images such that the app shows a random image each time the user opens the app.

I have searched "how to randomize splash screen for android" but it all needs to modify some java code (but I am writing a dart project). Is there another way like only modify .dart and/or .xml code?
I have added the second image to different places but none works. See below:

In launch_background.xml, the following only shows the splash_screen_1 image, splash_screen_2 is never shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_1" />
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_2" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the following only shows the splash_screen_2 image, splash_screen_1 is never shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_1" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_2" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is there a way to solve it in flutter? e.g. only modify .xml and/or .dart code and no need to modify java code? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'is there a flutter way'? Your question is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I mean not modifying the java code, only modifying .xml and/or .dart code

Comment: So your project is a regular android project, but you would like to run a dart class from there? I don't think think is a sensible approach. If you want a fully-fledged flutter app, use something like `IndexedStack`. If you want to write an android app in Java/Kotlin, you can use a `ViewSwitcher`.

Comment: Thank you, but my project is not a regular android project, but rather a flutter project. I have written all the code in dart (and none in java). I want to build the android app from flutter. But when I search online, they all provide java solutions so I am confused. I want to have some solution works in dart/xml but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Widget randomScreen(int max) {
  var rnd = Random();
  var num = rnd.nextInt(max);
  print(num);
  switch (num) {
    case 1: return SecondSplashScreen();break;
    case 2: return ThirdSplashScreen();break;
    default: return FirstSplashScreen();break;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: randomScreen(4),
    );
  }
}

class FirstSplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstSplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _FirstSplashScreenState createState() => _FirstSplashScreenState();
}

class _FirstSplashScreenState extends State<FirstSplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       color: Colors.blue
    );
  }
}


class SecondSplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondSplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _SecondSplashScreenState createState() => _SecondSplashScreenState();
}

class _SecondSplashScreenState extends State<SecondSplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       color: Colors.red
    );
  }
}


class ThirdSplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ThirdSplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _ThirdSplashScreenState createState() => _ThirdSplashScreenState();
}

class _ThirdSplashScreenState extends State<ThirdSplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       color: Colors.green
    );
  }
}
```